# matlab function files with two variables

Tags: function, matlab

i'm having some issues starting off with matlab and the articultion with function files. i have been asked the following.
"write a user defined MATLAB function file for the following function `z = (x^2 + 1)(y^2 - x)` The inputs of the function are `x` and `y` and the output is `z`. Name the function as `q2_func`. write the function so that `x` and `y` can be vectors.

A) use the function `q2_func` to calculate and display the value of z for x=-3 and y = 3.
B) use the function `q2_func` to calculate and display the value of z for x=[1 2] amd y = 3.

So far for my function file I have the following

`function [ z ] = q2_func(x, y)
x = (x.^2 + 1)*(y.^2 - x); 
end`

and for the actual matlab programming
`x1 = q2_func(-3, 3)`

when I hit run I get the error
`undefined function 'q2_func' for input arguments type double`

What am I doing wrong so far? any help appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2):

First, there is a mistake in your function, it should be `z = (x.^2 + 1).*(y.^2 - x);`.

Second, have you saved your function as `q2_func.m` in your current directory or somewhere on the MATLAB path? The error message indicates that MATLAB cannot find the file.